# split matrix-column without intermediate conversion to matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Say I've got a data.frame which contains matrix-columns. I'd like to transform these into separate columns. I've seen [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441301/transform-data-frame-matrix-column-into-columns) which suggests a good solution of `as.data.frame(as.matrix(...))`. However, if the columns/matrix-columns of the data.frame are a mixture of numeric and character, converting to matrix converts *all* columns to character.

I could do this via brute force, looping over the columns etc, but there must be a more elegant way of doing this. I played around with something like `do.call(cbind, sapply(..., data.frame))` which does in fact preserve numeric/character, but destroys the column names which is less than ideal (while the matrix-data.frame conversion keeps the column names looking nice).

For example,

```
> data(mtcars)
> mtcars$car <- row.names(mtcars)
> m <- model.frame(cbind(gear, am) ~ car, data = mtcars)
> head(m)
                  cbind(gear, am).gear cbind(gear, am).am               car
Mazda RX4                            4                  1         Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag                        4                  1     Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710                           4                  1        Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive                       3                  0    Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout                    3                  0 Hornet Sportabout
Valiant                              3                  0           Valiant
> str(m, give.attr = FALSE)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cbind(gear, am): num [1:32, 1:2] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ car            : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
> dim(m)
[1] 32  2
> m2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(m))
> head(m2)
                  cbind(gear, am).gear cbind(gear, am).am               car
Mazda RX4                            4                  1         Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag                        4                  1     Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710                           4                  1        Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive                       3                  0    Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout                    3                  0 Hornet Sportabout
Valiant                              3                  0           Valiant
> str(m2, give.attr = FALSE)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cbind(gear, am).gear: chr  "4" "4" "4" "3" ...
 $ cbind(gear, am).am  : chr  "1" "1" "1" "0" ...
 $ car                 : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
> dim(m2)
[1] 32  3
> m3 <- do.call(cbind, sapply(m, data.frame))
> head(m3)
  cbind(gear, am).gear cbind(gear, am).am            X..i..
1                    4                  1         Mazda RX4
2                    4                  1     Mazda RX4 Wag
3                    4                  1        Datsun 710
4                    3                  0    Hornet 4 Drive
5                    3                  0 Hornet Sportabout
6                    3                  0           Valiant
> str(m3, give.attr = FALSE)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cbind(gear, am).gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ cbind(gear, am).am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X..i..              : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
> dim(m3)
[1] 32  3
```

In this example, `m2` preserves the column names but loses the type, while `m3` preserves the type while loses the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `do.call` with `data.frame`

```
m4 <- do.call(data.frame, c(m, check.names = FALSE))
```

-output structure

```
> str(m4)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cbind(gear, am).gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ cbind(gear, am).am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ car                 : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
```

---

In the third case for deriving 'm3', OP used `sapply` to loop over the columns of a `data.frame` 'm' and then convert to `data.frame`. But, it does nothing in flattening i.e. the column from `matrix` is converted to `data.frame` in `list` and the `X..` in the column name is derived from the inner name because the 'car', a column in original 'm' was forced to be converted to a data.frame with no default column name

```
> str(sapply(m, data.frame))
List of 2
 $ cbind(gear, am):'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ car            :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X..i..: chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
```

Comment: For `m3` I was trying to convert the data.frame into a list of columns/matrices which could be passed to `do.call`. There's likely a better way to do that as well.

Comment: @Josh You may either use `asplit(do.call(data.frame, m), 2)` or `unclass(do.call(data.frame, m))`